Why my AWS ECS cluster is not showing the option to switch to code-deploy controller?
I am creating an application & deployment group in aws aws code-deploy, but I am facing the issue while creating the same. Screenshot for reference:

I have tried to update the code-deploy controller in the ecs fargate service, but the option itself is not available. I have tried to update ecs using aws-cli command, Unknown options: --deployment-controller, type=CODE_DEPLOY.
Attached cli error image here

there is no issue in the role that I have attached.
aws ecs update-service --service service-name --cluster cluster-name --deployment-configuration "deploymentCircuitBreaker={enable=true,rollback=true}" --deployment-controller type=CODE_DEPLOY
There are no available documentations on the internet.

"cli is throwning command not found" that just means you don't have the AWS CLI tool installed, or you don't have it in your path.
